# InstallUISequence for custom dialog with radiobuttons

Tags: dialog, wix, radio-button, custom-action, orca

My InstallUISequence looks as below in Orca:
CostFinalize->Dialog1->CA1->Dialog2->CA2->MaintenanceWelcomeDlg

Dialog1 has two radio buttons (rb1 and rb2):
- rb1 should show Dialog 3 after Dialog1 without going through CA1->Dialog2->CA2 and then show MaintenanceWelcomeDlg
- rb2 follows the InstallUISequence defined above and shows Dialog 4 before MaintenanceWelcomeDlg

However when I select rb1 this is what happens:
Dialog1->Dialog3->Dialog2

**How can I prevent Dialog2 from being called when rb1 is selected?**

NOTE: Dialog3 and Dialog4 are not on the InstallUISequence. They are only called using NewDialog from Next buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding a condition to the CA1, Dialog2 and CA2.

```
  <Custom Action="CA1" After="Dialog1">
    <![CDATA[rb_Prop = "valueX"]]>
  </Custom>
  <Show Dialog="Dialog2" After="CA1">
    <![CDATA[rb_Prop = "valueX"]]>
  </Show>

  <Custom Action="CA2" After="Dialog2">
    <![CDATA[rb_Prop = "valueX"]]>
  </Custom>
```